# Will a single CRON always finish even if it runs long?

Tags: php, cron

Lets say i have a CRON that runs every 2 minutes. If the cron ends up running long, does the next execution of that script stop the previous execution? Will the CRON always complete its task even if execution runs long and the next execution takes place?

Comment: You have maybe a timelimit for you scrip execution basicaly in PHP it's 30 seconds.

And no if you launch multiple times the same cron it not stop the previous occurence

Comment: @Inazo I didnt think that CRON and therefore PHP CLI had a time limit

Comment: Unless you have some blocking mechanism, the 2 scripts are treated as unique and each will run to completion

Comment: PHP CLI have time limit too, but you can to configure it in separate php.ini

Comment: @Inazo You can set one but by default they do not have a time limit

Comment: @Inazo From php.ini file `; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 120`

Comment: @RiggsFolly you've right : ; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI but i'll always found it with 30 in php.ini when i'll install my PHP with FPM version my PHP-CLI have always 30 value.

Comment: I didn't think the FPM was the CLI, 2 different things entirely

Comment: I've had the same PHP script run for days when triggered by cron, with new instances being ran daily. So yes, cron will still trigger a new script, will not stop the old one, and will run as long as it needs to unless you set a timeout or it hits an error.